# Перегрузка оператора < в c#

Tags: c#, дизайн-языка

У меня есть такой код:

```
public class Foo
{
    public static bool operator<(Foo l, Foo f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Foo!");
        return false;
    }
    //public static bool operator>(Foo l, Foo f)
    //{
    //    return f < l;
    //}
}
```

Я удивился, что в c# он не компилируется (сам пришел в с# после изучения с++). Соответсвенно возник вопрос, почему компилятор требует "парную" реализацию операторов <, >. Например в с++ такой код будет работать. Не могу понять причины такого дизайна в с#.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что C#, в отличие от плюсов, заточен не на максимальную эффективность, а на максимальную предсказуемость.

Он сам реализует операторы комбинированного присваивания, гарантируя, что `a+=b` будет работать так же, как `a=a+b`.

И он требует чтобы парные операторы были реализованы в паре. Если я могу написать `a<b`, то мне может захотеться написать и `b>a`, причём, я буду ожидать, что эти условия эквивалентны. Не знаю, почему они не стали генерировать второй оператор сами, но причины его необходимости кажутся достаточно понятными - программист будет интуитивно ожидать, что второй ему тоже доступен.

Comment: Я думал об этом, но если честно такой аргумент мне кажется сомнительным (я про например использование > вместо <). Интересен другой вариант, может компилятор в зависимости от контекста может использовать оператор > вместо написанного <

Comment: @LmTinyToon Учтите, что оператор <, > (и другие) не обязаны возвращать bool. Поэтому автоматически сгенерировать парный оператор в общем случае невозможно.

Comment: @kmv, ну вот и нашлась причина :)

Comment: @kmv, согласен. Но я все равно не понимаю,зачем нужно создавать парную реализацию. Если я допустим и не намереваюсь использовать оператор > вообще (возвращаемый тип не важен)

Comment: @LmTinyToon: Вы пишете оператор не для себя, а **для пользователей вашего кода**. Для себя вы можете делать что угодно: объявлять публичные поля, использовать вместо ивентов делегаты, как хотите. Но язык старается вам помешать делать неправильно, он старается, чтобы в коде было поменьше WTF.

Comment: @VladD, я просто исходил из с++ парадигмы

Comment: @LmTinyToon: Угу, C++ известен тем, что легкомысленно разрешает любую глупость. Например, вы можете вернуть указатель на локальную переменную из метода.

Answer (score 1):

[В документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8edha89s.aspx) сказано:

> При перегрузке операторов сравнения они должны перегружаться парами;
>   то есть если оператор == перегружается, оператор != тоже должен
>   перегружаться. Обратное также верно, и сказанное относится также к
>   парам операторов < и >, <= и >=.

Обратите внимание, что не все операторы могут быть перегружены. Кроме того, некоторые операторы имеют ограничения.

- **+, -, !, ~, ++, --, true, false** -    эти унарные операторы могут быть перегружены.
- **+, -, *, /, %, &, | , ^, <<, >>**  - эти бинарные операторы могут быть перегружены.
- **==, !=, <, >, <=, >=** - операторы сравнения могут быть перегружены
- **&&, ||** - условные логические операторы не могут быть перегружены, но
  они оцениваются с помощью & и | , которые могут быть
  перегружены.
- **[]**   - оператор индексирования массива не может быть перегружен, но можно определить индексаторы.
- **(T)x** - оператор приведения типов не может быть перегружен, но можно определить новые операторы преобразования
- **+=, -=, *=, /=, %=, &=, |=, ^=, <<=, >>=** - операторы присваивания не могут быть перегружены, но +=, например, оценивается с помощью +, который может быть перегружен.
- **=, ., ?:, ??, ->, =>, f(x), as, checked, unchecked, default, delegate, is, new, sizeof, typeof**   - эти операторы не могут быть перегружены.